# How to search first occurrence of string key in c# dictionary without LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have data in a dictionary in this way:

```
Dictionary<string, cls_CTCs> dict = new Dictionary<string, cls_CTCs>();
dict.Add("9814|30500994",Obj);
dict.Add("41377|30302099",Obj);
dict.Add("65793|30500337",Obj);
dict.Add("92894|30300795",Obj);
dict.Add("92894|30300826",Obj);
dict.Add("92894|30300827",Obj);
dict.Add("92894|30300828",Obj);
dict.Add("56936|30300894",Obj);
dict.Add("56936|30300365",Obj);
dict.Add("56936|30300485",Obj);
```

Where key is string type and value is an object of a class. I want to find first occurrence of a string in all the keys of this dictionary in like or startswith pattern. For example, if I search for "92894", then it should return the key "92894|30300795" and if I search for "56936", then it should return the key "56936|30300894".

I know it could be done easily by using LINQ, but I dont want to use LINQ as I would use this code in C# CLR Stored Procedure which does not allow LINQ. So, is there any extension method  or any other approach that I could achieve what I want?

Comment: What are the requirements? Does it need to be really fast? Or why not simply loop through the dictionary entries?

Comment: Same answer as your last question about dictionaries - you cant do partial key searches without linq - so use a for loop and yes it is slower - but it does sound more like your sql should be doing this for you

Comment: enumerate the dictionary's `AllKeys` and do a `String.StartsWith` on each to match the partial key, then return the match. But if that's your task, then the Dictionary is not the best choice of data structure. Look into Tries. LINQ would not help improving performance here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary.Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns all keys in the dictionary.

However the order of Keys in a dictionary is undefined, so finding the first one has no meaning - it will return any key that matches, at random.

```
// Returns a key which starts with prefix, or null if not found.
public string FindKey<T>(Dictionary<string, T> dict, string prefix)
{
    foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
    {
        if (key.StartsWith(prefix))
            return key;
    } 

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @HemantSisodia As this answer states, the order that the keys are returned in is undefined. This may appear to work as long as you only add keys to the dictionary. If you start removing keys, though, it may no longer return the keys in the order you want.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That is fine with me, because I wont remove the keys, I just wanted the first occurrence of that similar key.

Comment: @HemantSisodia Fair enough - but also be aware that because you are taking advantage of undocumented behaviour, a future version of C# could break this!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Alright mate, thanks! Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no other way for achieving it without a full iterative scan over the dictionary.

The reason is how the current implementation of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` internally works. All the keys are indexed using their hash codes (see the `Object.GetHashCode` method). So there is a fast and effective search of a key as a whole object only.

If you need to find some keys by a partial match (`StartsWith` or whatever), you just need to iterate over each key performing a comparison/lookup.

You can do it either using the dictionary's `Keys` collection or just iterating over the dictionary itself working with the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects.

Keep in mind that there is no particular order, however. So "the first occurrence" might be a requirement that is hard do fulfill.

You might want to use an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the objects' order is important.